# Separate loggers for different methods

Tags: java, log4j2

I use loggers to print traces that are specific to certain methods. That way when I want to debug my code I can activate traces in only those methods I care about.

I used to be able to do that with log4j v1. I would instrument selected methods with loggers like this:

```
private static void method1() {
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.examples.method1");
  logger.debug("Hello from method1");
  etc...
}
private static void method2() {
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.examples.method2");
  logger.debug("Hello from method2");
  etc...
}
```

Then in my log4j.properties file, I would activate the traces like this:

```
log4j.logger.org.examples.method1=debug
log4j.logger.org.examples.method2=debug
etc...
```

I am trying to replicate that behavior in log4j v2, but am having problems with it.

As far as instrumenting methods with loggers, I am doing OK. I do it the same way as with v1, except that I use LogManager.getLogger() instead of Logger.getLogger() (which does not exist in v2).

For activating the loggers, I need to use the v2 syntax, so I now do this:

```
logger.app.name = org.examples.method1
logger.app.level = debug

logger.app.name = org.examples.method2
logger.app.level = debug
```

The problem is that when I run code that invokes both method1 and method2, only the method2 traces appear. In order to see the method1 traces, I have to comment out the method2 properties. Note that I have tried adding the additivity = true to both loggers, to no effect.

Piotr (see answer below) says that I need to have a different value for the '.app' bit in the above code. So instead I should write something like this:

```
logger.1.name = org.examples.method1
logger.1.level = debug

logger.2.name = org.examples.method2
logger.2.level = debug
```

But this is really inconvenient for my use case because I have to:

- Make sure I use the same number on all lines that pertain to a given logger
- Make sure that I never use the same number for a different logger

One solution would be for me to write a macro that would automatically generate the two lines from the name of the logger. So, for a logger called org.examples.method1, it might generate:

```
logger.org_examples_method1.name = org.examples.method1
logger.org_examples_method1.level = debug
```

Pietr also suggested that I might use the .yml or .json syntax instead of .properties. But when I tried the .yml syntax, I had the same problem, namely, if I write this:

```
  Loggers:
    logger:
        - name: org.examples.method1
          level: debug
    logger:
        - name: org.examples.method2
          level: debug
```

Then only the method2 traces are being printed. And here, there does not seem to be a "second id" involved, so I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: The `app` after `logger.` must be a unique identifier for that logger, otherwise one property overrides the other. You can use `logger.1`, `logger.2` or whatever you want (as long as it does not contain a dot).

Comment: Hum, this works, but it is incredibly painful for my use case. I Now have to make sure that: (1) I choose a unique id  in the 'logger.someid.name=' line (2) make sure I use that exact same unique  id in the 'logger.someid.level=' line then (3) type the name of the logger (the one referenced in my java code) as the value for the 'logger.someid.name=' line. I may have to write an Emacs macro to generate the 'someid' from the name of the logger.

Comment: That is why the properties format is not the default one in Log4j 2.x. Use the XML or JSON format, which are less verbose.

Comment: I tried the .yml syntax, but I am having the same problem. See the bit I added at the end of my question.

Comment: YAML also does not accept multiple keys with the same name (`logger`).

Answer (score 0):

As you remarked the properties format is not the easiest one to use, since it requires at least to lines per logger and plenty useless identifiers to generate. By comparison you have:

- in the properties format:

  ```
  logger.<id1>.name=org.example.foo
  logger.<id1>.level=INFO
  logger.<id2>.name=org.example.bar
  logger.<id2>.level=DEBUG
  ```
- in the XML format:

  ```xml
  <Loggers>
      <Logger name="org.example.foo" level="INFO"/>
      <Logger name="org.example.bar" level="DEBUG"/>
  </Loggers>
  ```
- in the YAML format:

  ```yaml
  Loggers:
      logger:
          - name: org.example.foo
            level: INFO
          - name: org.example.bar
            level: DEBUG
  ```
- in the JSON format:

  ```json
  "loggers": {
      "logger": [
          { "name": "org.example.foo", "level": "INFO" },
          { "name": "org.example.bar", "level": "DEBUG" }
      ]
  }
  ```

There has been some propositions recently aimed at shortening the properties format: see [LOG4J2-3341](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3341), [LOG4J2-3394](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3394) or my own [PR #735](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/735).

Comment: Thx for providing a YAML example. I just realized that I should not repeat the 'logger' line. I should have just one 'logger' line with several -name and -level lines, one for each method logger I want. Problem solved.